# OpCodes.Castclass. Is it necessary?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

Is it necessary to emit OpCode.CastClass(typeof(A)) when you having a reference to instance of (B) on top of stack, where B is class, derived from A, when preparing for a call to method with argument of type A?

Addition:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void IFoo();

}

public class A:IFoo
{
    public void IFoo()
    {

    }
}
public class B:A,IFoo
{
    new public void IFoo()
    {

    }
}

var b = new B();

(b as IFoo).Foo();
((b as A) as IFoo).Foo();
```

Comment: What happens when you omit it and run the emitted code?

Comment: In both ways (emit | not emit) everything works fine.

Comment: So the answer is: no, it is not necessary.

Comment: But i'm afraid of not emitting castclass potentially may lead to problems with virtual calls or sms. else in future.

Comment: Using `callvirt` should be enough. Casting the instance to the declaring type should not be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have something like this:

```
class A
{
    public void Foo() { }
}

class B : A
{
}
```

and need to decide between:

```
B b = new B();
b.Foo();
```

and

```
B b = new B();
((A)b).Foo();
```

Both work. But the cast is not necessary, because `B` inherits all members from `A`.