# Is the Castclass OpCode necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, il

CLR allows me to set a field with an object reference regardless of whether a `Castclass` operation has been performed. Is it ok to set a field if there is certainty that the object reference on top of the stack is of the approperiate type? If so, does that mean that `Castclass` is a safety feature for use by compilers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpCodes.Castclass. Is it necessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265453/opcodes-castclass-is-it-necessary)

Comment: @Asad - Correct, but unfortunately that question has no definite answers.

Comment: The answer states that the cast (and therefore the casting opcode) is unnecessary.

Comment: @Asad - Again correct, but I stated _no definite answers_.

Comment: What does that mean? The definite answer to your question is that Castclass is not necessary if the type of the reference you're setting implements the type of the field. This is just basic OOP, has nothing to do with IL, and should be fairly obvious. This doesn't make casting redundant though. If you have a reference of type `object`, and because of your program flow you know that it is actually an instance of `IFoo`, you can cast it to `IFoo` using the `CastClass` opcode before using it somewhere where an `IFoo` is required.

Comment: Hard to guess what this is about, but the CLR certainly does not permit arbitrary object assignments.  The verifier checks for type safety before code can run.

Comment: @HansPassant - Please see http://pastebin.com/U1fuH5vC, here I am able to set a field with an invalid object reference. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what I'm supposed to look at, not the question it seems.  If you found a bug in the verifier then post it to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant - I think you didn't see the hyperlink, please try again.

Comment: The IL you're generating is invalid. You're probably an admin on the machine you're running this on, so it is skipping verification of the IL you generate, but if your run `peverify` on it you'll discover that the IL you're emitting is broken.

Comment: @Asad - It seems to run without error on a standard account. Eitherway I really must use those VS tools more often, they seem very handy.

Answer (score 0):

When you write CIL, you write it on virtual stack base language, not OOP language.

Castclass is an optional opcode to use for make sure that reference address is the class you want because in CIL everything could mess up easily.

This is example that I just change variant A from CA type into CB type and stock instance CB from B into A (alike what's you done in http://pastebin.com/U1fuH5vC).

```
.method public static void  Swap(class TestOOP.Module1/CA& A,
                                 class TestOOP.Module1/CB& B) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2

    ldarg.0
    ldarg.1
    ldind.ref
    stind.ref

    ret
}
```